# Will cookies be sent in cross-site context if sent between domain and subdomain?

Tags: cookies, dns, cross-site

If I have a server running on `api.mydomain.com` and the client running on `mydomain.com` and I'm using session cookies stored on the server for authorization, will the browser flag the cookie as cross-site? The reason I ask is because I know Safari does not allow cross-site cookies and Chrome will soon follow suit.